# Is the set of all continuous functions from a to b a topological linear space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

My college doesn’t require that students take topology (I don’t even know if they offer it). However I am currently working on a proof to show that a functional J[h] where $h \in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$ and $x_0 \in [a,b]$ is a fixed point in the given interval is a continuous linear functional. The functional is defined as $J := h(x) \to h(x_0)$. I’ve already shown that the functional satisfies homogeneity and J[g + h] = J[g] + J[h]. Now I’m left to show that the functional is continuous. I’ve read in the book “Introductory Real Analysis” by A.N. Kolmogrov and S.V. Fomin that it is sufficient to show that the continuity of a linear functional on a topological linear space need only be checked for a single point.

So my question is if $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$, the set of all continuous functions from a to b, is topological linear space? And if so, why?

Comment: The set of all real valued functions (over a fixed interval $[a,b]$) with the natural definitions of addition of functions and scaling of functions forms a vector (linear) space over the reals. The space $C[a,b]$ is a linear subspace of the previous space—the proof is a basic linear algebra exercise (a space is a subspace if and only if it is closed under linear addition). I am pretty sure this is addressed in Kolmogorov and Fomin but I’ll double check for reference.

Comment: Right I was able to prove that part, however I now need to prove that the functional defined is a continuous functional given any element of $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$. I know that the definition of a continuous functional is given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\sigma$ such that if $|| y  - \hat{y} || < \sigma$ then $|J[y] - J[\hat{y}]| < \epsilon$. However I don't know how to show this for all functions, and as such using the definition to show that it is continuous for one element of a topological linear space, then it is continuous for all elements in that space.

Comment: Actually I think I see what your saying, but is $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ a topological space? What makes it a topological space? Again I never took topology so sorry if my knowledge is lacking.

Comment: $C[a,b]$ may be equipped with a metric which in turn induces a topology. In fact, one can equip it with a norm (so it is a normed vector space) which in turn induces a metric which induces a topology. The typical choice is the “uniform norm” given by $\|f\|_\infty:=\sup_{x\in [a,b]} |f(x)|$. This norm induces a complete metric amongst other nice properties. Once again Kolmogorov and Fomin is a great reference for theory of metric space, topological spaces, and topological linear spaces. Other norms are used for other purposes, so which to use depends on context and aims.

Comment: So in particular you need to prove, given $\epsilon$ and $f$ in $C$, find $\delta >0$ such that $\|h-f\| <\delta$ implies $|J[h]-J[f]| <\epsilon$. Note the difference in norm signs from that of uniform norm on $C$ to absolute value on the real line. In other words: if the difference of the inputs of the functional, $\sup |h(x)-f(x)|$, is taken sufficiently small, can we show the difference in the output $|h(x_0)-f(x_0)|$ is then arbitrarily small?

Comment: Right and since $h$ and $f$ are elements of a topological linear space, it is sufficient to show this only for one element $f$ in the given space? Say I can choose $ f = x \in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$ and show that $J[h]$ is continuous at $f$ given a fixed $x_0$, and by this theorem - that it is sufficient to show continuity for one element of a topological linear space then the functional is continuous for all elements in the space - J[h] is continuous for all $h \in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$?

Comment: Sure but implicitly I was hinting that you can just directly argue because of the specific definition of $J$. For any continuous function (on $[a,b]$) $f$ we have, for any fixed point $x_0$ in the domain interval, that $|J[h]-J[f]|=|h(x_0)-f(x_0)| \leq \| h-f\|_\infty$ by virtue of the supremum figuring in the definition of the uniform norm, where $h$ is an arbitrary continuous function. For more complicated $J$ it helps to pick $f$ specifically and appeal to theorem you reference, of course.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for the help!